# Can't play video served from localhost when wifi is off on iOS 10

Tags: ios, ipad, ios10, wkwebview

Is it possible to play video served from local embedded server with `WKWebView` while offline?

I have a app developed with `WKWebView` that served from a embedded server.

I am serving local video and use `<vidoe src="http://localhost:8102/path/to/video.mp4"></video>` to play video.

It was working fine on iOS 9.x. Both online and offline (wifi and data off).
However on iOS 10 it doesn't play the video when wifi is OFF (tried on iPad Pro Wifi and simulator).
The error is `MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED`, basically, cannot reach to server. But when it runs on simulator, I can play the video on my desktop Safari.

I also tried UIWebView which behavies the same.

Steps to reproduce on simulator:

- Start a local server serve some mp4 file. e.g. http-server
- Open ios 10 simulator, load a mp4 file. e.g. http://localhost:8080/1.mp4
- Make sure it plays without issue
- Disconnect computer from internet (e.g. turn off wifi)
- On ios 10 simulator, load the same file.
- The video won't load this time

Same steps on ios 9 simulator works without issue.

Is any way to workaround this issue? I tried use `file://` url which doesn't work with `WKWebView`.

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

Comment: @New16 ha... it seems fix the problem on simulator. I will do some more testing on device.

Comment: @New16 `127.0.0.1` fixed it. Thanks!